# 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.Collections.IList'.' in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

```
     Models = new DataTable();
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = this;  
     GetModel();
     listCollectionView = new ListCollectionView((System.Collections.IList)Models);
```

I want to convert dataTable to Listcollection view in WPF

Comment: Well no... why did you *expect* to be able to cast `DataTable` to `IList`? (This has nothing to do with WPF really - you'd see the same exception in a console app.)

Answer (score 0):

To get `IList` you need first cast `DataTable` to `System.ComponentModel.IListSource`. So

```
new ListCollectionView( ((System.ComponentModel.IListSource)new System.Data.DataTable()).GetList() )
```

should work.